merge several columns of the same data into one
I've created a dataframe that adds data from several sources. Here is an example subset:
index   CompanyName   Source1site   Source2site   Source3site   City
1       Comp1         web1.com      Nan           web2.com      Paris
2       Comp1         Web2.com      web2.com      Nan           Nan
3       Comp2         Nan           site1.com     Nan           Oakland
4       Comp2         site2.com     Nan           Nan           London
5       Comp3         Nan           Nan           Nan           Mexico
6       Comp4         Nan           url1.com      Nan           Nan
7       Comp5         Nan           example.com   Nan           New York

Now Source1site, Source2site and Source3site are all basically website domain names just collected for CompanyName from different sources. I'm looking to merge these three columns in a way that it preserves data from other columns as well. This is the example output I'm looking for:
index   CompanyName   MergeSourceSite   City
1       Comp1         web1.com          Paris
2       Comp1         web2.com          Paris
3       Comp2         site1.com         Oakland
4       Comp2         Site1.com         London
5       Comp2         site2.com         Oakland
6       Comp2         site2.com         London
7       Comp3         Nan               Mexico
8       Comp4         url1.com          Nan
9       Comp5         example.com       New York

Really appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks,

Looking at both tables I was wondering ... why do you have Comp2/site1/London, Comp2/site2/Oakland, ... ?  why no Comp1/web2.com/Nan ? we should have Mexico even if no SourceSite for it?

Explain your logic clearly row by row.

You can achieve this by following:
df = your_dataframe

# Merge source columns into a single column 
merged_sources = df.melt(
    id_vars=["index", "CompanyName", "City"],
    value_vars=["Source1site", "Source2site", "Source3site"],
    value_name="MergeSourceSite" 
)

# Remove rows with NaN in the MergeSourceSite column 
merged_sources = merged_sources.dropna(subset=["MergeSourceSite"])

# Remove duplicate rows and reset index 
merged_sources = merged_sources.drop(columns= 
["variable"]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# Sort by index for a cleaner output 
merged_sources = merged_sources.sort_values(by="index").reset_index(drop=True)

It will give you the output you need.
